# Python's email package from the standard library inserts spurious linebreaks after S/MIME boundaries which seems to break S/MIME signing

Tags: python, email, smime, python-cryptography

I'm trying to use the cryptography library to sign a document.

The following script (`working.py`) works when it is executed from a directory that contains a private key and a certificate:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key, pkcs7, Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

with open('private_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    private_key_data = load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(),password=b'password')

with open('certificate.pem', 'rb') as cert_file:
    certificate_data = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read())

text_to_sign = ('Some text\n'
                'Hällöchen W€lt!\n'
                'Ändosa\n')

sys.stdout.buffer.write(
    pkcs7.PKCS7SignatureBuilder(
    ).set_data(
        bytes(text_to_sign, 'utf-8')
    ).add_signer(
        certificate_data, private_key_data, hashes.SHA256()
    ).sign(
        Encoding.SMIME, [pkcs7.PKCS7Options.DetachedSignature]
    )
)
```

I can execute this script as follows:

```
$ ./working.py > working.signed
$ openssl smime -verify -CAfile certificate.pem -in working.signed
Some text
Hällöchen W€lt!
Ändosa
Verification successful
```

I would like to add some extra metadata to the document.  Since I'm using pkcs7 with S/MIME encoding, I reached for Python's email and mime handling package from the standard library to accomplish this.  Note that I'm preparing a specially crafted document, and not really an email.  My goal is to enable the receiver to verify its authenticity of the document's payload (which is "`Some text\nHällöchen W€lt!\nÄndosa\n`" in my example).  The payload can contain line breaks and Unicode characters beyond ASCII.  I enhanced the script from above as follows (`nonworking.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import email
import email.policy

from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key, pkcs7, Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

with open('private_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    private_key_data = load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(),password=b'password')

with open('certificate.pem', 'rb') as cert_file:
    certificate_data = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read())

text_to_sign = ('Some text\n'
                'Hällöchen W€lt!\n'
                'Ändosa\n')

signed_document = email.message_from_bytes(
    pkcs7.PKCS7SignatureBuilder(
    ).set_data(
        bytes(text_to_sign, 'utf-8')
    ).add_signer(
        certificate_data, private_key_data, hashes.SHA256()
    ).sign(
        Encoding.SMIME, [pkcs7.PKCS7Options.DetachedSignature]
    ),
    policy=email.policy.default
)

# signed_document.set_param('charset', 'utf-8')
# signed_document['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate()
# signed_document['From'] = 'we@us.com'
# signed_document['To'] = 'they@them.com'
# signed_document['Subject'] = 'What the document is about'

sys.stdout.buffer.write(signed_document.as_bytes())
```

I can execute this script as follows:

```
$ ./non_working.py > non_working.signed
$ openssl smime -verify -CAfile certificate.pem -in non_working.signed

Some text
Hällöchen W€lt!
Ändosa
Verification failure
005EBA74547F0000:error:10800065:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c:1081:
005EBA74547F0000:error:10800069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:361:
```

The verification fails.  The problem seems to be that `non_working.signed` contains an extra spurious newline after the first boundary:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature";
 micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----2E2B6EF0B6E7CB564955721240B068C0"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------2E2B6EF0B6E7CB564955721240B068C0

Some text
Hällöchen W€lt!
Ändosa

------2E2B6EF0B6E7CB564955721240B068C0
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIGvQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIGrjCCBqoCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkq
hkiG9w0BBwGgggPbMIID1zCCAr+gAwIBAgIUDO1y0dqi2G2ds/8qXampRXN3+a8w
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwezELMAkGA1UEBhMCZGUxEjAQBgNVBAcMCU51cmVtYmVy
ZzEPMA0GA1UECgwGRXhhc29sMQwwCgYDVQQLDANDT1MxETAPBgNVBAMMCHBhdWwu
...
```

That is not the case for working.signed:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----0D7398911FD63AD56872B79624A2C78F"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------0D7398911FD63AD56872B79624A2C78F
Some text^M
Hällöchen W€lt!^M
Ändosa^M

------0D7398911FD63AD56872B79624A2C78F
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIGvQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIGrjCCBqoCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkq
hkiG9w0BBwGgggPbMIID1zCCAr+gAwIBAgIUDO1y0dqi2G2ds/8qXampRXN3+a8w
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwezELMAkGA1UEBhMCZGUxEjAQBgNVBAcMCU51cmVtYmVy
ZzEPMA0GA1UECgwGRXhhc29sMQwwCgYDVQQLDANDT1MxETAPBgNVBAMMCHBhdWwu
Y29tMSYwJAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhdwYXVsLmthbGV0dGFAZXhhc29sLmNvbTAeFw0y
...
```

The document `non_working.signed` can be made to verify, if one manually removes the spurious newline (the one before "`Some text`").

As you might have noticed, working.signed uses `\r\n` line breaks for the payload, while non-working.signed uses `\n`.  This is probably explained by the `email.policy.default` that I specified.  Surprisingly, to me, this does not seem to affect the verification of the signature.

In the source code of `non_working.py` I commented out the extra metadata that I wanted to add to the document headers.  When it is included `non_working.signature` can still be made to verify, if one only manually removes the newline after the first boundary.

The email package is configurable with countless knobs, so it is possible that I overlooked something.  Is this a problem with the email package, or did I do something wrong?  If this is a bug in the email package, can you think of a work around?

How can I modify `non_working.py` to generate a document that will verify?